# If u = Constant, then $S \equiv p(u,v)$ is a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

This has been my work so far:

I have a surface parameterized by $p(u,v) = p(u_0,v)$

To proof that it is a geodesic I used the following equations:

\begin{align*} 
\frac{d}{dt}\Big(E\dot{u} + F\dot{v}\Big) &=  \frac{1}{2}\Big(\partial_uE\ \dot{u}^2 + 2\partial_uF\ \dot{u}\dot{v} + \partial_uG\ \dot{v}^2   \Big) \\ 
\frac{d}{dt}\Big(F\dot{u} + G\dot{v}\Big) &=  \frac{1}{2}\Big(\partial_vE\ \dot{u}^2 + 2\partial_vF\ \dot{u}\dot{v} + \partial_vG\ \dot{v}^2   \Big)
\end{align*}

Since $u=u_0$, I know that
$$E = F = \partial_uE =\partial_uF = \partial_vE = \partial_vF= 0  $$
and
$G = p_v\cdot p_v, \ \partial_vG=\partial_v (p_v\cdot p_v)\ $ and $\ \partial_u G = 0$

The first equation I came up with $0=0$, but I can´t figure it out how to solve the second equation.

Thank you!

Comment: This is no longer a surface once you fix $u_0$. You have some very basic misunderstandings.

Comment: How would that be true? For example if $p(u, v)  = (u, v, \sqrt{1-u^2 + v^2})$, then $p(u_0, v)$ is not a geodesic unless $u_0 = 0$.